# scripting sftp with expect

Tags: sftp, expect, spawn

I have to script an sftp-access with password-authentification. Unfortunately our customer can't create a key-authentification on the server we have to access.

All the sftp-Commands are generated and written in a temporary file (tmp.txt). Following command works fine on the command-line:

```
sftp OnlineRegTest_BS@ftp.b-n-c.ch < tmp.txt
```

The problems starts when I'd like to use "expect" because I have to script it and use a password.

```
EXPECTSCRIPT=`cat <<EOF
    spawn sftp user@server < tmp.txt
    expect "password"
    send ${pass}
    send "\r" 
EOF`
expect -c "$EXPECTSCRIPT"
```

If I remove the "< tmp.txt" the connection will establish. But I need the commands from the tmp.txt. Here's the error-Message:

```
[root@xxx web]# ./transfer.sh
spawn sftp user@server < tmp.txt
usage: sftp [-1Cv] [-B buffer_size] [-b batchfile] [-F ssh_config]
            [-o ssh_option] [-P sftp_server_path] [-R num_requests]
            [-S program] [-s subsystem | sftp_server] host
       sftp [[user@]host[:file [file]]]
       sftp [[user@]host[:dir[/]]]
       sftp -b batchfile [user@]host
send: spawn id exp6 not open
    while executing
"send password"
```

Does someone have any ideas?

I also couldn't get it running with sftp -b... :-(

*edit for @glenn jackman*

```
EXPECTSCRIPT2=`cat <<EOF
        spawn sh -c {sftp user@server < tmp.txt}
        expect "password"
        send ${pass}
        send "\r"
        expect "sftp>"
        expect "sftp>"
        .....
        expect "sftp>"
        expect "sftp>"
        expect "sftp>"
EOF`
```

the tmp.txt looks like this:

```
cd d
put d/d1
cd ../e
put e/e1
put e/e2
cd ../f
put f/f1
```

Comment: Are you confusing your remote and local directory structure? You change directory to `d` on the server, then you put the local file `./d/d1` to the server. Do you have a **local** `./d` directory?

Comment: actually yes.. the local folder structure ist the same as on the target-server. For 3 languages a folder. (d, e and f) The same structure is on the server which i connect to. It's a requirement from our developer.

Comment: Can you use SSH keys? If yes, you don't need expect at all.

Comment: unfortunately not! that's the problem! :( our customer where the server stands doesn't have a key-authentification. And can't configure one!! :(

Answer (score 0):

Try spawning a shell to handle the redirection:

```
spawn sh -c {sftp user@example.com < tmp.txt}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm a step further now. But it's still not working as it should. The connect to the sftp-Server is now ok. But the commands of the tmp.txt are not getting executed. any idea to this?
If i put a lot's of "expect "sftp>" in the expectscript, it works.. but that's not really the goal. Details in the edit above.. (in the question)